# Swift2.0でUIColorのRGBa値をString型の変数に格納する方法

Tags: ios, swift

Xcode7.1、Swift2で開発をしています。
指定したピクセル座標のRGBa値をUIColorで返す機能（getColorメソッド）を実装し、
ViewController.swift内でprintメソッドで、コンソールに

```
UIDeviceRGBColorSpace R G B a   //R，G，B，aはFloatの値
```

という表示を出すところまでは成功したのですが、ここで得たRGBaの値もしくは
コンソールに表示された文字列を、コード内で扱えるようにString型の変数に
格納するためにはどうすればよいでしょうか？

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

自己解決しましたので、報告も兼ねて回答します。
getColorメソッドは[こちら](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25146557/how-do-i-get-the-color-of-a-pixel-in-a-uiimage-with-swift)のコードを参考に書いたのですが、
特段戻り値がUIColorである必要がなかったため、

```
func getColor(pos: CGPoint) -> UIColor
```

としていた部分を

```
func getColor(pos: CGPoint) ->(red: String, green: String, blue: String, alpha: String)
```

と書き換え、

```
return (r, g, b, a)
```

というように戻り値を記述することで、無事にRGBa値の値をString型の変数に格納することができました。

参考までにgetColorメソッドを掲載します。

```
func getColor(pos: CGPoint) -> (red: String, green: String, blue: String, alpha: String) {

    let imageData = CGDataProviderCopyData(CGImageGetDataProvider(self.CGImage))
    let data : UnsafePointer = CFDataGetBytePtr(imageData)
    let pixelInfo : Int = ((Int(self.size.width) * Int(pos.y)) + Int(pos.x)) * 4
    let rFloat = CGFloat(data[pixelInfo]) / CGFloat(255.0)
    let gFloat = CGFloat(data[pixelInfo+1]) / CGFloat(255.0)
    let bFloat = CGFloat(data[pixelInfo+2]) / CGFloat(255.0)
    let aFloat = CGFloat(data[pixelInfo+3]) / CGFloat(255.0)
    let r = rFloat.description
    let g = gFloat.description
    let b = bFloat.description
    let a = aFloat.description

    return (r, g, b, a)
}
```

どなたかの参考になれば幸いです。